# I lost all my progress in pokemon go after deleting app?

Tags: pokemon-go

I deleted my Pokemon go app and reinstalled, in turn I lost all my data and had to restart. But my "nick name" is already taken . So is my account still valid ? How do I recover it?

Comment: If it is asking you to use a new nickname then you are logging in with a different google or trainer account than you originally registered with.

Comment: But I have only one gmail account and that's how I logged in

Comment: What about a Pokémon Trainer Club account?

Comment: @user158882 as stated in peanuts answer (as well as my answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277051/pokemon-go-app-contains-data/277053#277053) your data is not gone. I would suggest that you double and triple check or retry signing in with your account. If it makes it easier for you you can simply clear the data from the app rather than reinstalling it (for android at least, not sure about iPhone)

Comment: Do remember that you can sign up for a Trainer Club account with your Gmail account. Could make it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Like Theyna said,

> If it is asking you to use a new nickname then you are logging in with a different google or trainer account than you originally registered with.

**You did not lose any of your data.** Your data is stored in relation to your Pokémon Trainer Club or Google account.

Simply sign in with the same account you signed in with the first time, and you should have your data back.